# How do you do a countdown?

Tags: usage, numbers

For example, when JAXA launches a rocket, or people count the seconds to the New Year, do they use し or よん to count 4? do they use しち or なな to count 7?

Comment: The rocket launch was a nice idea; how about a link to a video of someone doing repetitions of an exercise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually when you count, you use `よん` for '4' and `なな` for '7'. That applies to when you [count down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDSkhsbHwXI).

> じゅう　きゅう　はち　**なな**　ろく　ご　**よん**　さん　に　いち

However, in some situations, pronouncing a certain sequence of numbers became so frequent end became a fixed expression. In that case, '4' and '7' may be pronounced `し` and `しち`, respectively. That includes a situation of counting up:

> いち　に　さん　**し**　ご　ろく　**しち**　はち　きゅう　じゅう

Comment: I wonder why you changed the wording from "so frequent that ..." to "end" (I think you meant "and"). The former sounds much more natural to me. Anyway I rolled back my edit and I'll leave it to you to make any changes if necessary.

Comment: @Lukman Thanks. I prefer your previous edit. My edit was a typo. I meant to improve it grammatically.

Comment: +1 Because I had never noticed before that 4 and 7 are commonly said differently depending on whether counting down or up. Now that I think of it, though, that seems to be true.

Comment: @sawa: Considering your answer, was I wrong or not here? [How to choose between “よん” (yon) vs “し” (shi) for “四” (4) and “しち” (shichi) vs “なな” (nana) for “七” (7)?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/328/how-to-choose-between-yon-vs-shi-for-4-and-shichi-vs/336#336).