# Why do some numbers have two readings?

Tags: pronunciation

Generally, when we read or count, 4, 7 and 9 are read only as "よん", "なな", "きゅう", seperately. However, in some cases, 4 is read as "よ" rather than "よん", 7 is read as "しち" rather than "なな", and 9 is read as "く" rather than "きゅう". Therefore, I would like to ask some question.

i) When is 4 read as "よ", "よん", or both?

ii) When is 7 read as "しち", "なな", or both?

iii) When is 9 read as "く", "きゅう", or both?

iv) Why do we not say "しじゅう", "しちじゅう", and "くじゅう" when counting 1 to 100?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/328/5010

Comment: Note: This is just a related link rather than answer.

Comment: Another one: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20881/7810

Comment: Note (again!): This, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "four" or "nine" on its own, it's almost always よん and きゅう in modern Japanese. しち is somehow relatively common as a standalone word, too, but you can always stick to なな. (いち, に, さん and し are on-readings but よん is a kun-reading. However, よん took the place of し for the most part, because し was aurally less distinctive and [し is associated to death](https://www.tofugu.com/japan/number-four-superstition/). なな are preferred especially in math or financial contexts because しち sounds a bit similar to いち.).

However, し, しち and く are used in the following contexts.

- In month names: 四月【しがつ】, 七月【しちがつ】, 九月【くがつ】 (なながつ is uncommon but acceptable. よんがつ and きゅうがつ sound very strange.)
- In 七時【しちじ】 and 九時【くじ】 (4 o'clock is よじ, not しじ. ななじ is also acceptable. きゅうじ is always wrong.)
- In fixed (usu. on-on) compounds: [四方【しほう】](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%9B%9B%E6%96%B9), [七五三【しちごさん】](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shichi-Go-San), [九九【くく】](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B9%9D%E4%B9%9D)
- In さんし, ろくしち, etc. (see: [What is the correct expression of 10/20, 20/30, 30/40 etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68582/5010))
- To describe an age without 歳/才: 十九【じゅうく】の春, 二十四【にじゅうし】で嫁に行く, 四十【しじゅう】からの健康法 (I don't know why, but this is probably a poetic/literary custom? Usually you can say 二十四歳【にじゅうよんさい】, etc.)
- When you count **up** only using on-yomi (see: [How do you do a countdown?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2364/5010))
- As mnemonics to remember numbers (see: [Rules for slang of Japanese numbers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/853/5010))
- Old speakers of some dialects may say しじゅう/しちじゅう/くじゅう.

Comment: However, when we count up, 40, 70 is yutou-yomi(よんじゅう、ななじゅう). not on-yomi. Also, 90 is kan'on "きゅう" is used, not go-on "く". Then, what is 44, 77, 99 when count up?

Comment: @Niconii よんじゅうよん, ななじゅうなな (or less commonly しちじゅうしち/ななじゅうしち), きゅうじゅうきゅう. しじゅう is acceptable only when you talk about age, "40 (years old)" or "in one's forties". 4/7/9 each has a little different history related to the Japanese culture or sound system, so you have to except some irregularities.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know when 4 is read as "よ", "よん", or both. Also, I don't know when 7 and 9 are read as "なな", "きゅう" only or "なな or しち", "きゅう or く".