# Japanese counters

Tags: counters

In Japanese, there are so many counters(助数詞). So I'm asking more counters other than 月(しがつ、しちがつ、くがつ) or 時(よじ、しちじ、くじ).

i) What counter makes 4 read よ or し?

ii) What counter makes 7 read しち?

iii) What counter makes 9 read く?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some numbers have two readings?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77772/why-do-some-numbers-have-two-readings)

Comment: I'm asking about counters(助数詞).

Comment: Don't the examples help?

Comment: I wanna know more about counters other than 月, 時. Answer, please :)