# choice of ひと ふた vs イチ ニ etc. with counters

Tags: counters

Scanning a long list of counters, the Chinese derived イチ ニ numerals seem to be prevalent. Is there any pattern or logic to the exceptions, i.e. when the native ひと ふた numerals are used?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "the native いち に system". 「イチ、ニ、サン」are 音読み{おんよみ}, the Chinese pronunciation. 「ひと、ふた、み」are 訓読み{くんよみ}, the native pronunciation.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5616/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42550/9831