# "Yon" vs. "Shi" in school names

Tags: readings, rōmaji

I've tried Voicetext.jp and Google's text to voice service to read this

> 四中の

It reads something like

> Yon-chū no

But Google suggested this romanization, which left me doubtful

> Shi-chū no

So, I have been redirected to a [similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/328/how-to-choose-between-%E3%82%88%E3%82%93-yon-vs-%E3%81%97-shi-for-%E5%9B%9B-4-and-%E3%81%97%E3%81%A1-shichi-vs) discussing why there is different pronunciations of the numbers 4, 7 and 9 (maybe there's more).

From the given answers, I can't decide how to read things like

> 足立区立第四中学校

Because none of the examples addressed there were close enough to school names, rankings and such...

Comment: What is the context in which you found this text? If it is an abbreviated name of a school (from 第四中学校 or something, maybe?), it's probably _yon-chuu no_. That said, I should note that relying on automated services to romanize Japanese is unlikely to be reliable.

Comment: I don't think this is really about rōmaji.  It seems like the question would be the same if you talked about the readings よん versus し in kana.

Comment: I suspect even the question here might help clear up your confusion: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/328

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, it is fairly easy: do not think that 四 is an isolated entity. It comes with 第, with `第四｛だいよん｝`, meaning `The fourth`.

In this case, whenever you encounter a counter, go with the 訓｛くん｝読｛よ｝み. This was highlighted in the answer you linked:

> Kunyomi is typically used in cases where you point out you have X of some item.

For example, you would say 四枚｛よんまい｝ to count flat things, 四本｛よんほん｝ to count cylindrical things, 四番目｛よんばんめ｝ which is another way of saying fourth, 四匹｛よんひき｝ to count animals and so on...

Comment: Whenever...? [第四高等学校](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%AC%AC%E5%9B%9B%E9%AB%98%E7%AD%89%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1-686580)